# Simple sub menu navigation not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, html-lists

Creating a simple navigation with sub menus. Every time I hover over the `ul` it shows `display: block`, the sub menu otherwise is always `display:none`.

Right now: The hover feature is not working.

This is where im trying to display the `ul` . **Are my selectors wrong? Not sure.**

```
    nav > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong? Also is my css clean or can it be any shorter?

Full html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        nav
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="main-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </div>
                <ul class="items">
                    <li><a href="#">items</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">items</a></li>
                        <ul class="sub-items">
                            <li><a href="#">subs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">subs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">subs 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <div class="items-after-sub-list">
                        <li><a href="#">items</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">items</a></li>                  
                    </div>      

                </ul>           
        </nav>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
    html {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}


header {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 1rem;
    height: 20px;
}

.main-nav {
    display: flex;
}
.main-nav li {
    padding-right: 1rem;
}

.main-nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.items {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    right: 15px;
 }
nav  {
    list-style: none;
 }

.items li {
        line-height: 2.5rem;

}
.items li a {
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}

.items-after-sub-list{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 143px;
}
.sub-items {
    position: relative;
    left: 72px;
    bottom: 48px;
    list-style: none;
 }

.sub-items  li a {
    color: black;
    background-color: green;

}
li a {
    transition: background 1s; 
}
nav a:hover {
    background-color: silver;
}

nav > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Your selector is indeed wrong, but what **exactly** are you trying to do? You're trying to make it so that when you hover over the `<ul>`, all of the `<li>` elements get `display: block`?

Comment: so when I hover over contacts, .items menu shows, and then when I Hover over one of the items li .sub-items ul show.\

Comment: I don't think I've specified which li item should have the sub-menu so because it doesn't matter this is for test

Comment: The problem is that `contact` is in a completely different section than your drop-down (`main-nav`). You'll need to **completely** restructure your HTML in order to achieve what you're looking for. I'll create an answer for this, but be aware that what you're asking for **cannot** be achieved without either JavaScript or preferably an HTML restructure.

Comment: I've created the div main-nav simply so I can use the flex feature. Can I not use flex on navigation is some way with a different html structure?

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could share your solution for this @ObsidianAge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector `nav > li:hover > ul` is indeed wrong, for two reasons:

- First, it's wrong because you don't have any `<ul>` elements inside of `<li>` elements. You have one sub-menu, but its a direct child of another `<ul>` element.
- Second, it's wrong because it would **never** equate to valid markup. A `<li>` element **must** have a `<ul>`, `<ol>` or `<menu>` parent. Using `<div>` as a parent is **[obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)**.

In addition to this, your structure is also wrong; 'Contact' is in `div.main-nav`, and as such has no way to access the drop-down without JavaScript (as CSS has **[no parent selector](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/)**).

Instead of using JavaScript, I would recommend a pure CSS solution by altering your HTML structure a little bit. Each 'level' should be contained as a child of the parent in the HTML. In my example, I've denoted that an element has children with the `.more` class.

First, you'll need to hide all **child menu items**, and simultaneously display the 'root' element (which can be achieved with the child selector `>`):

```
#collapse li {
  display: none;
}

#collapse > li {
  display: block;
}
```

Then you can use the following to display the next level of children:

```
#collapse li.more:hover > ul > li {
  display: block;
}
```

Because of the double use of the child selector, this only ever selects the very next level. Having said that, because there is no child selector between `#collapse` and `li.more`, it will hit **every** `li.more` element under `#collapse`, allowing for indefinite recursion.

This can be seen working in the following minimal example:

```css
#collapse .more {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -1em;
}

#collapse .more:before {
  content: "+";
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#collapse .more ul {
  text-indent: 0em;
  cursor: initial;
}

#collapse li {
  display: none;
}

#collapse > li {
  display: block;
}

#collapse li.more:hover > ul > li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="collapse">
  <li>Top-level without children</li>
  <li class="more">Top-level with children
    <ul>
      <li>Sub-level without children</li>
      <li class="more">Sub-level with children
        <ul>
          <li>Child 1</li>
          <li>Child 2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hovering over the `.more` elements reveals the direct children, and **only** the direct children.

Hope this helps! :)